# Program prints null value

Tags: java, null, pojo

I am trying to print an array using `toString()` but there are `Null` values that print when I'm expecting numbers. I must have caused a memory leak in my program. Please help

```
public class StudentData
 {
    // instance variables 


 private String firstName,lastName;
 private double[] testScores; //array
 private char grade;

public StudentData()
{
   firstName = "";
   lastName = "";
   testScores = new double[5];
   grade = '*';
   }

 /**
 * Constructor for objects of class StudentData
 */
 public StudentData(String fName,String lName,double ... list)
   {
       // initialise instance variables
       firstName = fName;
       lastName = lName;
       testScores = list;
       grade = courseGrade(list); //calc 
    }

public char courseGrade(double ... list) //returns a char (grade)
 {
    double total = 0, sum = 0, average = 0;

     for ( int x = 0; x < list.length; x++)
        {
       total += list[x]; //sum
       average = total/list.length; //average
    }

    if (average >= 90)     //determines the grade
        return 'A';
    else if (average >= 80)
        return 'B';
    else if (average > 70)
        return 'C';
    else if (average > 60)
        return 'D';
    else
        return 'F';
    }

 public String toString ()
   { 
    return firstName + "\t" + lastName + "\t" + testScores + "\t" + grade; 



    }

}
```

And my tester class:

```
public class TestProgStudentData
{
public static void main (String [] args)
{

   StudentData student1 = new StudentData("John", "Doe",89, 78, 95, 63, 94);

   StudentData student2 = new StudentData("Lindsay", "Green", 92, 82, 90, 70, 87, 99);

    System.out.println(student1);
    System.out.println(student2);
   }
 }
```

The names print clearly, as well as the grade, but the values on the test do not print.

Comment: `this.testScores = testScores` is equal to `this.testScores = this.testScores` in absence of a local variable or parameter `testScores`. Recheck your parameter declaration. Should it not say `double... testScores`?

Answer (score 3):

The only thing that you ever assigning to `testScores` is `testScores`

```
this.testScores = testScores;
```

which is null.  it is only intialized in the default constructor which is never called.

Unless you need the `testScores` as an array for later use, why not create a string containing the values as you iterate over them in `courseGrade`

e.g

```
// field
StringBuilder testScores  = new StringBuilder ();

// `courseGrade`
for ( int x = 0; x < list.length; x++)
{
     testScores.append (list[x]).append (",");
     ....
```

Comment: what should I do to fix it? Get rid of default constructor, don't use local variables...

Comment: I need it for later, that's why i put it in the constructor

Comment: well OK, change my `testScores` to something like `testScoresAsString` or whatever.

Comment: I changed the constructor, and now i'm getting data leaks instead of NULL strings, so i'm still stuck.

Comment: what on earth are data leaks?

Comment: Something that looks like this [D@13efbf4. I was told that it is called data leaks

Comment: It's a memory leak, not a data leak. I'm sorry.

Comment: No it is NOT.  It is simple printing out the reference value of the object.  You should maybe print as `return firstName + "\t" + lastName + "\t" + testScoresAsString.toString() + "\t" + grade; `

Comment: you can use Arrays.toString(testscores) to get the list as a string.  if you add an array reference to a string construction it addes a representation of the reference.  the [ indicates an array, the D indicates a double (so array of doubles) the final @#### is a memory reference.

Comment: @lhasadad , i came upon the same issue again recently. What's the way to get around this?

Comment: Was the problem the test scores were not printing again?  not sure exactly what you meant by same issue.

Comment: @AviParshan The problem is when you try to print an `object` and it does not have an overriden `toString` method is that it will use the `toString` method of the `Object` class - so in my answer I created a StringBuffer and added the output to it.  BTW, how about accepting my answer? see https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers